# Gulp.js Ignoring source Control Files

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I have a project structure some thing like:

```
web
   a.html
   CVS
   folderA
          b.html
          CVS
   c.html
```

I am trying to use gulp to copy src to dest
However i want to ignore all CVS folders [souce control] in all levels.
Tried gulp-filter or !{dir} at src, nothing works...

Here is my gulpfile.js code for the same:

Doesnt work:

```
 gulp.task('default', function() {
 gulp.src([myDir+'/**'])
.pipe(filter(['*', '!'+myDir+'/CVS/**']))
.pipe(gulp.dest(jboss_dir));
 });
```

Nor Does this:

```
 gulp.task('default', function() {
 gulp.src([myDir+'/**', '!'+myDir+'/CVS/**'])
 .pipe(gulp.dest(jboss_dir));
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. You're only excluding the top level `CVS` folder. To exclude *any* folder/subfolder named `CVS`, you need to use `'!' + myDir + '/**/CVS/**'`.
2. `CVS/**` will select all the contents of a `CVS` folder, but not the folder itself. If you want to exclude both the folder *and* its contents, do it explicitly: `'!' + myDir + '/**/CVS', '!' + myDir + '/**/CVS/**'`.